# Spring.Net get the context Resource from a resource file?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, spring.net

In spring you always use the `web.config`/`app.config` for storing your objects like so:

```xml
<spring>
    <context>
        <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects>
        <description>An  example that demonstrates simple IoC features.</description>
    </objects>
</spring>
```

or

```xml
<resource uri="~/config/objects.xml" />
```

As sometimes I'm running under some service which doesn't have this web.config I'd like to add my objects to a resource file (`*.resx`).

How would I do that, so i can get a full `IApplicationContext` as if I would call `IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();`?

So basically instead of using the web.config I want to use a resource file to store my objects and initialize my application context with those objects.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to use a resource (resx) file?

Comment: as said in the post: "sometimes I'm running under some service which doesn't have this web.config". Ultimately this service doesn't have any config so it needs to get the stuff from somewhere else..

Comment: I meant to ask why not load it from an XML file like `var ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("objects.xml")` ? That can be done without any configuration app.config file. You can also embed these configuration files in your assembly if you want, so I don't see the immediate benefit of using a resx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanics aren't *quite* the same as defining your objects in a RESX file (which isn't supported at all), but you *can* easily achieve what's probably your underlying goal: having your config internalized within your assembly rather than externalized into a separate XML file (web.config, app.config, or even just a stand-alone anything.xml file).

You can do this using Spring.NET's `assembly://` resource prefix (e.g., `assembly://MyAssembly/MyService/objects.xml`)/  See http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#d4e412 for more details.

Comment: Perfect. Just didn't know about that.